# Ruby portal.new parent, klass

Tags: ruby

So I am simply trying to create a Client class inside a Module and then use a Portal Class inside the Client initialize method to create a Response class. I am trying yo create a way that will allow the Client class access to the Response class methods and instance_variables. Below is a rough ruby file and module/class architecture I have created to test all of this:

```
module Test
    class Client

        attr_accessor :response

        def initialize
            conn
            @response = Portal.new self, Response
        end

        def conn
            @conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://api.openweathermap.org') do |faraday|
                faraday.request  :url_encoded             # form-encode POST params
                faraday.response :logger                  # log requests to STDOUT
                faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  # make requests with Net::HTTP
            end
        end
    end

    class Portal
        def initialize parent, klass
            @parent = parent
            @klass = klass
        end

        def method_missing method, *args, &block
            @klass.public_send method, @parent, *args, &block
        end
    end

    class Response

        attr_accessor :conn, :res

        def initialize client, params
            @client = client
            conn
        end

        def conn
            @conn
        end

        def get
            @res = conn.get do |req|
                    req.url '/data/2.5/weather'
                    req.params['q'] = @city_country_state
                    req.params['APPID'] = @consumer_api_key
                    req.params['units'] = @units
                end
        end
    end
end
```

using binding.pry I "tested" my program and received the following with only the error occurring in the end:

```
[1] pry(main)> new = Test::Client.new
=> #<Test::Client:0x00007fbaca975540
 @conn=
  #<Faraday::Connection:0x00007fbaca975310.....>
@response=
  #<Test::Portal:0x00007fbaca96e1c8
   @klass=Test::Response,
   @parent=#<Test::Client:0x00007fbaca975540 ...>>>
```

After creating and seeing the Portal class creating a Test::Response class inside, I check the Test::Client @response variable:

```
[2] pry(main)> new.response
=> #<Test::Portal:0x00007fbaca96e1c8
 @klass=Test::Response,
 @parent=
  #<Test::Client:0x00007fbaca975540.....>
```

Since the @response variable was set correctly and inherited correctly I move to trying and call Test::Response.get from within new = Test::Client.new:

```
[3] pry(main)> new.response.get
NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for Test::Response:Class
from test.rb:47:in `public_send'
```

Line 47 in test.rb refers to the Test::Portal line of:

`@klass.public_send method, @parent, *args, &block`

inside the `method_missing` function:

```
def method_missing method, *args, &block
    @klass.public_send method, @parent, *args, &block
end
```

How do I allow the created Test::Client object to use the get method inside Test::Response and set @conn using the Test::Client's @conn and conn method in the initialize method.

Comment: `Response` instance variable `@conn` is never set and will always be `nil` I think this is an issue. Also right now you are trying to call `Response.get` but `get` is an instance method so maybe try initializing `@response` as `@response = Portal.new self, Response.new(conn,{})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response instance variable @conn is never set and will always be nil I think this is an issue. Also right now you are trying to call Response.get but get is an instance method so maybe try initializing @response as @response = Portal.new self, Response.new(conn,{})

Via:  engineersmnky Nov 13 at 20:29